# WinCE 5.0 How Can I Get Directory

Tags: c#, file, text, path, windows-ce

Hi all firstly sorry for my English but i hope you can understand me..
Im doing a project on VS2008-Smart Device Project-WinCE 5.0 Project.
I need to create text file to DATA folder which is under the main directory of program.

There is my code, there is no error messege but its not creating text file.My directory always returns null.
Whats wrong with that code?

```
if (Form2.dosya_adi != null)
{
    string cfile = Form2.chosenfile;
    path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\DATA\\" + cfile+ ".txt";

}
else 
{
    path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)+"\\DATA";
}
try
{

    StreamReader Read_File= File.OpenText(path);//Dosyayı açmaya çalış olmaz ise catch bloğuna geç
    ReadFile.Close();
}
catch
{

    StreamWriter Write_File= File.CreateText(path+ i.ToString()+".txt");// yeni dosya oluştur.
    Write_File.Close();
}`
```

And heres the form2 which includes listbox and listbox shows directory for if there is a file or not..

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
path = path + "\\DATA";
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles();
foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(fi.Name);
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        chosen_file = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("HATA:Hiçbir Değer Seçilmedi!"); // That means error:no value chosen!
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever debug? What are the values in the variables?

Comment: At what point? You should get a `NullReferenceException` in all possible places I can see in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not prepare the `path` variable properly. In one case it contains a file name, in another case it contains only a path name:

```
if (Form2.dosya_adi != null)
{
    string cfile = Form2.chosenfile;
    path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\DATA\\" + cfile+ ".txt";

}
else 
{
    path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)+"\\DATA";
}
```

Then you try to open a file - even though the variable does not contain a file name in the first place. If that leads to an exception, you try to create a file, but actually, you're not adding a path separator to the path. So I think your `catch` block should read:

```
StreamWriter Write_File= File.CreateText(path + "\\" + i.ToString() + ".txt");// yeni dosya oluştur.
Write_File.Close();
```